# Ignore elements when certain attribute is null when mapping objects

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping

I am using the following function to map a network object to a domain one.

**Mapping function**

```
    fun getLocationLocalModel(input: LocationSearchResponse): List<Location> {
        return input.locations.map { location ->
            return@map location.bbox?.let {
                Location(
                    name = location.name,
                    countryCode = location.countryCode,
                    north = location.bbox.north,
                    south = location.bbox.south,
                    west = location.bbox.west,
                    east = location.bbox.east
                )
            }
        }.filterNotNull()
    }
```

**Network DTOs**

```
data class LocationSearchResponse(
    @SerializedName("geonames")
    val locations: List<Location>
)

data class Location(val bbox: Bbox?, val countryCode: String, val countryName: String,
                    val geonameId: Int, val lat: String, val lng: String, val name: String)
```

**Domain Model**

```
@Parcelize
data class Location(val name: String, val countryCode: String, val north: Double, val south: Double, val east: Double, val west: Double) : Parcelable
```

What I want is to ignore the objects where bbox is null so they are not added to the resulting list of locations.
This function works, but there must be a better/simpler way to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about [List<T>.mapNotNull()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html)?

Comment: Yes! That works as well, thanks :) but I still need to keep this line: `return@mapNotNull location.bbox?.let {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Animesh mentioned in the comments, simply change your statement to `mapNotNull` -- there's no need to use the `return@` syntax there:

```
return input.locations.mapNotNull { loc ->
  loc.bbox?.let { bbox ->
    Location(loc.name, loc.countryCode, bbox.north, bbox.south, bbox.west, bbox.east)
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could filter first, then use `!!` to dereference:

```
return input.locations
  .filter { it.bbox != null }
  .map { loc->
    val bbox = loc.bbox!!
    Location(loc.name, loc.countryCode, bbox.north, bbox.south, bbox.west, bbox.east)
  }
```

Personally the former seems more readable to me.